# How does linux schedule the multiple child processes?

Tags: fork

I'd like to fork thousands of processes that can be run in parallel together to hide IO latency.

My program maintains around 2000 child processes and one waiting thread that waits for child process at any time, but it seems that all processors are not utilized fully.

When I execute the htop, only some processors are fully utilized, but the others are not.

Each process executes a very short function (about 0.1 sec) and exit.

Is it because children exit too early to be measured by the htop for showing CPU utilization?

Because when I make a forked processes to run infinite while loop I could see full utilization on all cores...

I am curious whether the processes are executed in parallel but not measured in htop or they are not executed in parallel..

Comment: Off topic, but spawning 2000 childs seems overkill just to perform async IOs...

Comment: You want to execute a task that includes I/O and CPU processing. You have several cores (say, `Nc`), which can, in the best case, make CPU processing up to `Nc` times faster. Having more threads than `Nc` cannot speed up *CPU* processing, but it can help if you are waiting on a lot of very small I/O events - for instance, running something similar to an IRC server. Can you describe the extent to which your task is I/O bound and CPU bound?

Comment: Yeah that is the reason that I spawn lots of children processes. Is there any way to measure how my child process is bounded to cpu or io?